# Exceeded cursor quota 100 when fetch from local datastore in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I know there must be lots of cursors are not closed. But Parse dose not have any method to do it. Hope Parse developer can help me have a look.

Code: fetch from local datastore if there is no need to update from cloud

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_CLASS);
    if(!remote) {
        logD("fetch from local server");
        query.fromPin(PIN_LABEL);
    }
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if(null == e) {
                logD("get list size " + list.size());
                if(remote) {
                    ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground(PIN_LABEL, new DeleteCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException parseexception) {
                            ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(PIN_LABEL, list);        
                        }
                    });
                }
                initialize(list);
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Below is the ParseException.

```
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process 23995    exceeded cursor quota 100, will kill it 01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995): at android.database.CursorWindow$Injector.checkQuota(CursorWindow.java:85) 01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):     at android.database.CursorWindow$Injector.addQuota(CursorWindow.java:73)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at android.database.CursorWindow.recordNewWindow(CursorWindow.java:810)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:192)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase(2.then(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:214)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase(2.then(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:205)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task(0.run(Task.java:486)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:358)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:369)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:415)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:407)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at bolts.Task(0.run(Task.java:486)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-07 13:57:24.386: W/System.err(23995):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)))))
```

Comment: What is the Parse lib version ?  To update recent version may help you.